# SQL 2005 Analysis Services Installation problem

Tags: sql, ssas, failed-installation

I get this error message when installing SQL 2005 Analysis services.

The  cabinet File 'sql.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot  be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the  CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

Im installing from an ISO file downloaded from MSDN. How could anything be missing from it?
When searching the .ISO file I noticed the file SQL.cab is not there.

Anyone fixed this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a 64Bit Vs 32Bit problem? Only thing I can think of. This link has some suggestions as regards not using a mounted ISO image as a virtual DVD http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/showpost.aspx?postid=351235&siteid=1